# How to get a part of a quaternion? e.g. get half of the rotation of a quaternion?

Tags: quaternions

if I have a quaternion which describes an arbitrary rotation, how can I get for example only the half rotation or something like 30% of this rotation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you do it for a regular complex number? I'm not sure what you want exactly, but I'm pretty sure you could do the exact same thing for quaternions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for are exponent and logarithm formulas for quaternions, which can be found on the Wikipedia page on [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Exponential.2C_logarithm.2C_and_power). The Wikipedia page even gives a formula for raising a quaternion to an arbitrary power, which is exactly what you want. If your original rotation is given by $q$, and you want to take 30% of this rotation, you simply take $q^{0.3}$.

Comment: Thank you all for answering! @user32086: Yes I was looking for that! If a combination  of rotation with quaternions is done by multypling them, it is the logical step that the exponet is doing the factor. It is a pity that I do not get it on my own!

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure what formula for a general rotation you have, but it *should* depend upon an angle through which you are rotating. Doesn't your formula look something like $R(\Theta, u)$ where $\Theta$ is the angle of rotation, and $u$ is a unit vector which tells you the axis of rotation?

If so, you just replace $\Theta$ with $p\Theta$ where $p$ is just some decimal form of a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [Wikipedia on quaternions and rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).

To the benefit of all: One can encode a rotation $T\in SO(3)$ as a quaternion $q+ q_1 i+ q_2 j + q_3 k$ of norm $1$. Here $q=\cos{\theta\over2}$ and $(q_1,q_2,q_3)=\sin{\theta\over2}{\bf a}$, where ${\bf a}$ denotes the unit vector on the axis of $T$ and $\theta$ the rotation angle of $T$. The essential point is that to the composition of two rotations $T_1$, $T_2\in SO(3)$ corresponds the product of the two associated  norm-$1$ quaternions.

As to your question: From the given quaternion $(q,{\bf q})$ you can read off the rotation angle $\theta$ (there are some sign conventions to observe) and the axis ${\bf a}$. For $\sqrt{T}$ (or another fraction of $T$) the axis is the same, but you will need a pocket calculator to compute $\cos\theta'$ and $\sin\theta'$, where $\theta'$ denotes the desired fraction  of $\theta$.